# Multiple AngularJS apps on same server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to put 2 (or more) angular apps on the same NodeJS server. Basically what I want is:

- mydomain.com/clientapp - end user app, ex: a buyer
- mydomain.com/userapp - a user that will create content. ex:a seller with his products
- mydomain.com/admin - the team that can approve and delete stuff

I am using ui-router ($stateProvider) to create the routes and load the pages. The thing is that I want to be able to write relative paths on my apps so that if I need to rename the base url from clientapp to client, I don't need to change all my apps urls.

```
// this should be routed to admin/clients. Relative path
state('listClients', {
        url: '/clients',
        templateUrl: 'modules/clientes/views/list-clients.client.view.html'
    }).

// this is how I am currently doing. 
state('listClients', {
        url: '/admin/clients',
        templateUrl: 'modules/clientes/views/list-clients.client.view.html'
    }).
```

The other strange thing that is happening is that when I set my angular app to a url, it kill the last / and add #! directly on the app name:

```
mydomain.com/app 
becomes mydomain.com/app#!/main // ugly as hell
wanted mydomain.com/app/#!/main // little better
```

How can I:

- properly setup AngularJS and ui-route to use the base path to all its requests?
- solve the ugly url issue?

Comment: Did you have a question ?

Comment: yeap. Edited the question.

Comment: Do you have a base href= element in your html head section?

Comment: I have tried the base element but it seems that it has some side effects on some libraries and on #anchor elements

Answer (score 1):

First App folder

```
  app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/app1')));
```

Second App folder

```
  app.use('/crm', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/app1/app2')));
```

Done! Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try ui.router.stateHelper

```
angular.module('admin', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.stateHelper'])
  .config(function(stateHelperProvider){
    stateHelperProvider.setNestedState({
        name: 'admin',
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'admin.html',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'listClients',
          url: '/clients',
          templateUrl: 'clients.html'
        }
      ]
    });
  });
```

once you want to change the module to clientapp you just need to change the module name and the url

```
angular.module('clientapp', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.stateHelper'])
  .config(function(stateHelperProvider){
    stateHelperProvider.setNestedState({
        name: 'clientapp',
      url: '/clientapp',
      templateUrl: 'clientapp.html',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'listClients',
          url: '/clients',
          templateUrl: 'clients.html'
        }
      ]
    });
  });
```

2.As for the ugly issue,I have no idea about it.Sorry for that.

Comment: You can try `$locationProvider` of `angular.js` to slove ugly issue.